# How to go from lat/long data to surface plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot

Creating a surface plot from lat/long data with the Z-axis being the amount of times that a certain lat/long position occurs

I have tried creating pivot tables with pandas, but I seem to not get it to work. They are not plotting correctly.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['latitude', 'longitude'], 
aggfunc='count')

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (18, 18))
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x = (df2['latitude'])
y = (df2['longitude'])
z = (df2['count'])

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.1)
fig.colorbar(surf, aspect = 5)
plt.show()
```

This is the pivot table, normally my data is just (lat, long). In the pivot I have counted the amount of hits at a certain lat/long position. I think the problem lies in the index of the pivot, you can see that 'count' is one row higher.

```
                count
latitude longitude  
20.1    1.1        3
20.2    1.2        3
        1.3        6
20.3    1.2        5
        1.5        5
20.4    1.1        6
        1.2        6
20.5    1.3        3
        1.4        1
        1.6        4
```

Comment: what's wrong with the plot? Also looks like you have some missing latitude entries

Comment: The latitude entries are not missing. A single latitude can have multiple longitude combinations (and the other way around). Then I counted the amount of times this specific lat/long exists in my dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by flattening the table using the following code: `df2_flattened = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_records())`. It now plots successfully, because the Latitude, Longitude and Count are all filled in nicely.